# chronicle vs chronicle-queue package

Tags: java, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I'm just getting started with chronicle queue - however I'm a bit confused on which API to use for reading/writing to the queue. Specifically [chronicle-queue-5](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/net.openhft/chronicle-queue/5.17.17) vs [chronicle-3.5.*](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/net.openhft/chronicle/3.5.3)

I've gone through this [link](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue#contents) which basically uses chronicle-queue API , but there are others like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-chronicle-queue) which uses chronicle.

What is the difference between these 2 below?

```
 Chronicle chronicle =  ChronicleQueueBuilder.indexed(_location).build();
 ExcerptAppender appender = chronicle.createAppender();
 appender.startExcerpt();
 appender.writeUTF("Hello World");
```

vs

```
ChronicleQueue queue = ChronicleQueue.singleBuilder(_location).build();
final net.openhft.chronicle.queue.ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();
 try (DocumentContext dc = appender.writingDocument()) 
 {
     dc.wire().write("hello").text("world " );
 }
```

The Javadoc documentation for [ChronicleQueue](https://static.javadoc.io/net.openhft/chronicle-queue/5.17.17/net/openhft/chronicle/queue/ChronicleQueue.html) 
and 
[Chronicle](https://static.javadoc.io/net.openhft/chronicle/3.5.3/net/openhft/chronicle/Chronicle.html) seems very similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both writing a message to a chronicle queue. I belive this

```
Chronicle chronicle =  ChronicleQueueBuilder.indexed(_location).build();
ExcerptAppender appender = chronicle.createAppender();
appender.startExcerpt();
appender.writeUTF("Hello World");
```

can now be written in chronicle queue 5 like this

```
try (final ChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary("temp-dir").build()) {
   final ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();
   appender.writeText("Hello World");
}
```

Or if you wanted to store `key`:`value` data, like this

```
try (final ChronicleQueue queue = SingleChronicleQueueBuilder.binary("temp-dir-2").build()) {
  final ExcerptAppender appender = queue.acquireAppender();
  try (DocumentContext dc = appender.writingDocument()) {
    dc.wire().write("hello").text("world");
  }
  DumpQueueMain.dump("temp-dir-2");
}
```

you can use

```
DumpQueueMain.dump("temp-dir-2");
```

to see how the data is stored, for example

```
# position: 131360, header: 2
--- !!data #binary
hello: world
```